# Why is the following Spring Boot + HATEOAS with mongodb not working (MarshalException)?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hateoas

I am attempting to use spring-data-mongodb with the spring-hateoas and am getting a javax.xml.bind.MarshalException exception through testing. How can I get around this issue? Are there annotations or other steps I am missing?

my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My "UserResourceAssembler.java":

```
@Component
class UserResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<User, Resource<User>> {

    String customersRel = "customers";

    @Override
    public Resource<User> toResource(MyObj u) {

        try {
            User user = new User("John");
            Collection<Link> links = new ArrayList<Link>();              
            return new Resource<User>(user, links);
        }
        catch (Exception throwable) {
            throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

My "User.java" representing a mongodb document:

```
@Document
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class User {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private String occupation;

  public User() {}
  public User(String occupation) {
     this.occupation = occupation;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
return String.format(       
                "{id:%s, occupation='%s'}",
                ttid, occupation);
      }


}
```

My "UserController.java":

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(User.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {
   @Autowired
   UserResourceAssembler userResourceAssembler;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/name/{user}")
    Resource<User> testUser(@PathVariable String user) {
        return userResourceAssembler.toResource(new User("Teenager"));
    }
}
```

In my Application.java I included the following annotation:

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
```

My issue is why am I getting error when I visit:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/name/doesnotmatterrightnow
```

The problem based on the error message is with the line:

```
return userResourceAssembler.toResource(new User("Teenager"));
```

The following is the full error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not marshal [Resource { content: {id:null, occupation='Teenager'}, links: [] }]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

type Exception report

message Could not marshal [Resource { content: {id:null, occupation='Teenager'}, links: [] }]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not marshal [Resource { content: {id:null, occupation='Teenager'}, links: [] }]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:138)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
root cause

javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
root cause

com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:235)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:250)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:102)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
root cause

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class sample.User nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:572)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:94)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
```

Comment: Are you sure that userResourceAssembler is injected into the class UserController since you do not use any annotation for the field?

Comment: Autowiring it appears to help the controller see it, but it is unable to "marshall" spewing a MarshalException.

Answer (score 17):

just add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Worked for me as well, any insight into why we have to explicitly declare the media type ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missed @XmlElement on User class

**Edit1**

I got it [Resource.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/Resource.java) not have @XmlSeeAlso for the User class so the JAXB can not find it in context, you can use the below UserResource and replace all Resource with this new class, it is working now.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({User.class})
public class UserResource extends Resource<User> {

    public UserResource() {
        this(new User(),null);
    }

    public UserResource(User content, Iterable<Link> links) {
        super(content, links);
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated post, I tried the atXmlRootElement above the User class, but same MarshalException.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't occupation be followed by : like id?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this spring-webmvc JAXB XML marshalling issue for *days*, trying every workaround I could fathom. I've now opted to use Jackson, replacing `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` with `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` which works out-the-box, as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class RestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
    }

}
```

N.B. I struggled to get the Java config to pick up the change in `HttpMessageConverter` because I also had `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in Spring's xml context which appeared to override the Java config.